# iOS 7 Messages: Fixed UITableView while still being able to bring up textfield?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, keyboard, message

I've done a lot of research before asking this question and haven't found a thorough answer.  Forgive me if it's been asked somewhere else.  I have been working on a messaging app for a few weeks now. Taking into account a typical messaging app (text field at bottom for user input with a table to store messages, pictures etc.) I understand that when the keyboard is shown the whole view must be pushed up to get the UITextField above the keyboard to show user input.  I examined the native messages app on iOS 7 however, and I noticed that when the keyboard is shown ONLY the UITextField is moved up from the bottom of the view and the table view stays fixed (at least that's how I believe they are doing it).  I know the table stays at a fixed point because when you scroll down to older messages at the top of the table, the most recent messages can be seen blurred behind the keyboard and can go all the way down the view itself while still having the keyboard visible.  My question here is: is it possible to have a fixed table view while still being able to bring the text field up above the keyboard to show user input?  In other words, is it possible to move just the text field up without having to move the whole view itself up?

Comment: I tested here the 2 most popular messaging apps for iOS and they do move the whole view up with the keyboard, so maybe I didn't get exactly what you want. The messages are inside a scroll view, which is moved up while still staying scrolled to the bottom. Now if do you want the table "fixed", your last messages will be covered by the keyboard when it shows up, right? iOS doesn't move anything by itself, so if you want to move only the text field, you can set only the text field frame. I'm adding this as a comment as I didn't clearly understand, hope to have helped anyway :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Well, I guess what I'm trying to achieve is having the table fully accessible when the keyboard is up, after moving the view. Since the view gets moved up with the keyboard, it isn't possible to scroll the length of the table with the keyboard visible.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the inputAccessoryView of the original textfield to be another textfield?

```
self.textFieldAtBottomOfView.inputAccessoryView = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 30)];
```

that way you'll get a textfield that floats above the keyboard. You might need to style it to look like your first textfield and the user would think that it moved up above the keyboard on focus.